# Last whitespace in 2D arrays; matrices

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have the entire program running and working perfectly except for one task.
In my for loop when I try to print my product_matrix array I get an extra space (" ") because I add a space after each iteration.

I tried an if else argument for each column and row for loop but I've been getting no luck. Been stuck on just this part for a few hours and I thought it was time to ask experts for help.

[Here is what it should look like and what program is doing instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb4wv.png)

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int first_matrix[10][10];
  int second_matrix[10][10];
  int product_matrix[10][10];
  int column = 0, row =0;
  int x = 0, y = 0, m = 0, n = 0;
  string temp;
  int value;

  // putting user input into my first_matrix array.
 cout << "Enter first matrix:" << endl;
 while(true){
    getline(cin, temp);
    if (temp.length() == 0){
     break;
    }
stringstream ss(temp);
column = 0;
while (ss >> value){
  first_matrix[row][column] = value;
  column++;
}
row++;
}
  // assigning length of cols and rows
  x = row;
  y = column;

  // putting user input into my second_matrix array.
  row = 0;
  cout << "Enter second matrix:" << endl;
  while(true){
    getline(cin, temp);
    if (temp.length() == 0){
      break;
    }
    stringstream ss(temp);
    column = 0;
    while (ss >> value){
      second_matrix[row][column] = value;
      column++;
    }
    row++;
  }
  m = row;
  n = column;

 // checking if first and second matrix arrays have compatible dimensions.
  if (y == m){
    // multiplying first and second matrix and putting it into the product_matrix
    for(row = 0; row < x; row++){
      for (column = 0; column < n; column++){
        product_matrix[row][column] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < m;  k++){
          product_matrix[row][column] += (first_matrix[row][k] * second_matrix[k][column]);
        }
      }
    }
    //printing product_array.
   cout << "The product is:" << endl;
   for (row = 0 ; row < x; row++){
      for (column = 0; column < n; column++){
        cout << product_matrix[row][column] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
  }
  else
     cout << "The two matrices have incompatible dimensions." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe not the best solution but try to change `cout << product_matrix[row][column] << " ";` to `cout << product_matrix[row][column] << (column < n - 1 ? " " : "");`

Comment: this just printed a 1 after the columns and a 0 after the last column

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose between a newline character and a space based on index in your print loop:

```
for (row = 0 ; row < x; row++){
    for (column = 0; column < n; column++){
        cout << product_matrix[row][column];
        cout << (column == n - 1) ? "\n" : " ";
    }
}
```

This code will print a newline charatcer if you're at the last (n - 1) column, and a space for all other columns. You will not need `cout << endl` in the outer loop using this method.

If you're unfamiliar with the

```
(condition) ? statement1 : statement1;
```

procedure, it's a simplified if-else. It's equivalent to

```
if (condition) {
    statement1;
} else {
    statement2;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem. ):

Comment: It printed `#0#1 \n #0#1 \n`

Comment: When I try ` cout << (column == n - 1) ? endl : ' '; ` I get an error: overloaded function with no contextual type information for that line. And which code statement would you like to see? The printing my matrix_product section?

Comment: I got it! I put `if(column != n -1) cout << " "; else cout << endl;`

Comment: Wow haha, so weird, this is semantically the same as the answer I gave before. Oh well, glad you got it out :)